# Would a high quality USB 3 SSD beat the speeds of a SATA II internal 7200rpm for gaming?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sata, usb-3

I have a gaming laptop and a desktop that I switch between pretty regularly due to not being home often. Rather than purchasing two SSDs, I was considering whether I could get away with getting a single USB 3 SSD and installing the games I needed on it instead!

I currently have SATA II , 7200rpm drives drives in both. Standard drives, basically. I'm looking to see a performance increase on load times on both machines, and was curious whether the USB 3 SSD would be able to outperform them in this regard or not. It seems like it would, but I've heard latency across USB 3 can actually be pretty bad, so I don't want to put out the money necessary to get this drive and find out that, in actuality, it comes out slower!

Just for a side note- the laptop does not have an esata drive, so I that isn't an option. :-\

So what do you guys think: Would a high quality USB 3 SSD beat the load speeds of a SATA II internal 7200rpm for gaming?

By external SSD, I mean an SSD drive in a USB 3 enclosure for 2.5" drives (claims 5Gbps)

Comment: Well [USB-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0) has a 5Gbit/s transfer rate while [SATA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_2.0_-_3_Gbit.2Fs_-_300_MB.2Fs) has only a 3 Gbit/s transfer rate. This would make seem that USB-3 is better than SATA. Reality is that there are a lot of things running in the background and most likely you won't get near any of those speeds. This being said, if a USB-3 can function well with a lot of different I/O operations, the SSD should be faster.

Comment: There are so many uncontrolled variables here that it's impossible to give anything remotely resembling a definitive answer; I can guarantee that USB 3 at full bandwidth is going to outperform SATA 2 at same, and that a 7200RPM drive isn't going to be able to saturate a SATA 2 channel in any case, but USB 3 won't be any faster if your enclosure's or machine's USB interface can't keep up. All that said, and reiterating the caveat that you'd need to do comparative benchmarks to get a real answer, I would expect to see better performance out of the SSD than out of a 7200RPM hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

There are several factors you'd have to take into account for both the desktop and the laptop;

**USB3**

What chipset do you have for this? [Not all give the best performance](http://vr-zone.com/articles/usb-3-0-speed-tests-7-way-host-controllers-roundup/13358.html).

Any other devices on the USB bus? On the USB3 bus?

**SSD**

High-end or low-end? [Because there's been some turmoil in the SSD market recently](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-recommendation-benchmark,3269.html).

Are all of the features fully supported by your operating system?

Since most SSDs are designed to interface w/ a SATA-based controller, what management/performance features do you lose when you go over USB3?

**GAMES**

Just because you specified the path to the USB3 drive during the installation, doesn't mean that there aren't a few hundred lines in your registry and dozens of other files scattered throughout your operating system's drive.

This is true for most Windows-based software.

Comment: Not actually answering, skips the internal drive, but adds interesting topics.

Comment: I'm sure the poster already has a feel for how fast the internal drives are on each system. "Would an internal SSD or an external USB3 SSD be faster?" was the boiled-down question (as I read it).

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 Techcruch [did an experiment](http://techcrunch.com/2010/02/05/esata-is-faster-than-usb-3-0-at-least-right-now/) between eSata and Usb 3.0. In their tests eSata was faster. They do not specify which version of Sata they are using.

However:

Take a look at [MaximumPC's review](http://www.maximumpc.com/ocz_enyo_128gb_usb_30_ssd_review) of the OCZ USB 3.0 SSD drive. The speeds averaged about 170 MB/s

Compare that to [a review](http://www.legitreviews.com/wd-scorpio-black-750gb-notebook-hard-drive-review_1658/10) of the WD Black 750 2.5 inch. The speeds max out at about 113MB/s

Based on these benchmarks, I believe SSD on USB 3.0 will be faster than a 7200 rpm on Sata 2